# Run block of code for two variables with different types and common trait

Tags: rust

I have the following (simplified) situation:

```
trait Z {
  fn apply(&self);
}

struct X { ... }
impl Z for X { ... }

struct Y { ... }
impl Z for Y { ... }


fn some_func() {
  ... do_some_stuff_and_initialise_variables
  let x: X = ...;
  let y: Y = ...;
  for z in &[x, y] { // does not work what is the type of z?
     ... doing a lot of stuff involving a lot of the variables initialised in the outer scope
     z.apply();
  }
}
```

What is the Rust way of handling a situation like this?

Of course I can extract a generic function for the block that gets executed in the for loop but then I have to explicitly create function arguments for all the variables from the outer scope that get used which is a lot of overhead so I would like to avoid this.

I could also work with `dyn Z` types but that would probably mean a runtime overhead which I also want to avoid, because it is not needed in this situation.

Comment: If you want to avoid runtime polimorfism (`dyn`) and don't want to repeat yourself then you will have to use some sort of _macro_ (which shouldn't be to difficult to write).

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I tried the macro approach, but the problem is that if the "block" is an argument to the macro then the block doesn't know what `z` is and the compiler complains. If I use a closure as an argument to the macro then the compiler wants to know the type of the argument which again results in the same problem (there are no generic closures).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea where your attempt failed, but a macro works just fine, the key is to define it where the initialized variables are already in scope so you can access them:

```rust
trait Z {
    fn apply(&self);
}

struct X;
impl Z for X {
    fn apply(&self) {
        println!("apply x")
    }
}

struct Y;
impl Z for Y {
    fn apply(&self) {
        println!("apply y")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = "bar";
    let x: X = X;
    let y: Y = Y;
    macro_rules! doit {
        ($($z:expr),*) => {
            $(
                println!("{foo:?}");
                $z.apply();
            )*
        };
    }
    doit!(x, y);
}
```

alternatively, like suggested, you can use dynamic dispatch:

```rust
// …
    for z in [&x as &dyn Z, &y] {
        println!("{foo:?}");
        z.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: There should be no need to define the macro within the scope of the variables; `macro_rules! apply { ($($i:ident),+) => { $($i.apply();)+ } }` defined outside the scope will work [just fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7355370f461273198f91a39f88d36379).

Comment: @user2722968 but the code block is *"doing a lot of stuff involving a lot of the variables initialised"* specifically there is no need to define it with `x` or `y` in scope, but the rest of the used variables need to be.

Comment: Ah nice, I think what I missed is the fact that one can define macros within a function I always defined it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to mimic dynamic dispatch with an `enum` (this can be automated thanks to [`enum_dispatch`](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/latest/enum_dispatch/)).

```rust
trait Z {
    fn apply(&self);
}

struct X;
impl Z for X {
    fn apply(&self) {
        println!("X::apply()")
    }
}

struct Y;
impl Z for Y {
    fn apply(&self) {
        println!("Y::apply()")
    }
}

enum XY {
    X(X),
    Y(Y),
}
impl Z for XY {
    fn apply(&self) {
        match self {
            Self::X(x) => x.apply(),
            Self::Y(y) => y.apply(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = XY::X(X);
    let y = XY::Y(Y);
    for z in &[x, y] {
        z.apply();
    }
}
/*
X::apply()
Y::apply()
*/
```